# Rabbitmq inNode.js with amqplib not broadcasting fanout messages

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, node-modules

This script should be like a messenger for rabbitmq studying meanings. I'm trying to run a message broker with a fanout exchage.

The problem is: messenges aren't being broadcasted. Those are being sent in a load balance fashion. How can I broadcast those messages like a real fanout exchange?

```
const amqplib = require('amqplib');
const readline = require("readline");

class Chat {

    async init() {
        await this.configureChannel();
        await this.configureConsumer();
        await this.configureCommandLine();
    }

    async configureChannel() {
        const conn = await amqplib.connect('amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672');
        const ch = await conn.createChannel();
        await ch.assertExchange("chat", "fanout", {});
        const { queue } = await ch.assertQueue('messages');
        await ch.bindQueue(queue, 'chat', '');
        this.ch = ch;
    }

    async configureConsumer() {
        await this.ch.consume("messages", logMessage);
        function logMessage(msg) {
            if (msg.content)
                console.log("\n[*] Recieved message: '%s'", msg.content.toString())
        }
    }

    async configureCommandLine() {
        const commandLine = readline.createInterface({
            input: process.stdin,
            output: process.stdout
        });
        this.commandLine = commandLine;
    }

    async run() {
        const prompt = () => {
            this.commandLine.question("Message: ", async (mensagem) => {
                debugger;
                if (mensagem === "sair") {
                    return this.commandLine.close();
                }
                await this.ch.publish("chat", 'messages', Buffer.from(mensagem), {});
                prompt();
            });
        }
        await this.init();
        console.log("\nChat\n");
        prompt();
    }

}

const chat = new Chat();
chat.run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you run multiple instances of this script as is, the issue here is that you're using one queue for all consumers. `fanout` exchange sends each message it received to all the queues that are bound to the exchange. But each queue (if it has multiple consumers) will work in a round-robin fashion (assuming there's some limit on prefetch count). To achieve `fanout` behaviour you need to run each instance of the script with a different queue.

Something along these lines (not tested):

```js
    ...
    async configureChannel() {
        const conn = await amqplib.connect('amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672');
        const ch = await conn.createChannel();
        await ch.assertExchange("chat", "fanout", {});
        this.ch = ch;
    }

    async configureConsumer() {
        const { ch } = this;
        const { queue } = await ch.assertQueue('', { exclusive: true });
        await ch.bindQueue(queue, 'chat', '');
        ch.consume(queue, logMessage);
        function logMessage(msg) {
            if (msg.content)
                console.log("\n[*] Recieved message: '%s'", msg.content.toString())
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: It just needs a correction I made in the question at the ch.assertQueue(...). This method is async and needs an await